# OpenSSL::HMACError: EVP_PKEY_new_mac_key: malloc failure message error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, rvm

I'm trying to reset my password in my ruby ​​app but I'm getting this message

[image: 1]

OpenSSL::HMACError (EVP_PKEY_new_mac_key: malloc failure)

That's my setUp:
Ruby 3.1.2
RVM for version management
Rails 7
Bundler Gem
sqlite DB

(openssl 1.1.1f)

I'm a windows user but I have the ubuntu22.04.1 LTS terminal on my machine

I've been tried to openssl 3.1.2 (the last version by documentation), but the same error appears

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and fixed by creating new master key. You need to remove the credentials.yml.enc file and then run this command

> EDITOR="nano" rails credentials:edit